# There was no endpoint listening at (Service Bus)) for sharepoint app = Cannot register AppEventReceiver.svc on Microsoft Azure Service Bus:

Tags: sharepoint, azure, azureservicebus, sharepoint-apps

1st I opened a new Sharepoint App Project from the Book:
Pro Sharepoint App Development (APress)

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=68C060F1B173BAA9!51983&authkey=!AH2c9Msfs2m9KJg&ithint=file%2crar

2nd. I went to my azure account, created a service bus namespace and copied the connection string
http://screencast.com/t/G4w0EXeYYMdT

3rd I pasted that into visual studio
http://screencast.com/t/8PXdt2QuTwAH

4th. I disabled firewall
http://screencast.com/t/kqOlWxSZ9Hk

5th. I press F5 to deploy the App. I click then on Trust and then the Apps says there was an error, I close the browser window inside Visual Studio

After 30 seconds I get this:

```
@"Error 1
        CorrelationId: 4f1a0952-1102-47c0-83f3-62f85952bdf9
        ErrorDetail: The remote event receiver callout failed.
        ErrorType: Transient
        ErrorTypeName: Intermittent
        ExceptionMessage: There was no endpoint listening at https://levalencia1.servicebus.windows.net/2772163249/415041792/obj/25b23141-8ec2-4982-9134-09f8d2c02620/AppEventReceiver.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
        Source: Common
        SourceName: Common App Deployment
```

Update 1:
I cancelled my sharepoint online subscribtion 60 days ago, and when I reactivated it, I had to purchase the license again, however doing this made no difference.
Please note I am just creating a blank app, sharepoint hosted or provider hosted, once I put to true the App Installed Event, the App is not deployed (when pressing F5) in Visual Studio.

The app shows an error on Site Contents, so I close the in-browser window and it says on the output the above message, I even recreated the developer site collection, I recreated the service bus namespace, I disabled firewall.

```
@"Error 1
        CorrelationId: 06821605-2c94-4df6-9146-c934d1cca93d
        ErrorDetail: The remote event receiver callout failed.
        ErrorType: Transient
        ErrorTypeName: Intermittent
        ExceptionMessage: There was no endpoint listening at https://levalencia.servicebus.windows.net/2772163249/415041792/obj/25b23141-8ec2-4982-9134-09f8d2c02620/AppEventReceiver.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
        Source: Common
        SourceName: Common App Deployment
```

I also noticed in the output sharepoint tools window the following:

```
Cannot register AppEventReceiver.svc on Microsoft Azure Service Bus: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ACS auth, not SAS as auth for the service bus namespace as it seems to be completely broken for RER debugging.

If you don't have a namespace configured for this auth (seems like you can't create new ones with it), then use the Azure CLI cmdlet `New-AzureSBNamespace -Name "NewNamespace" -Location "West Europe"`

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot create new ACS enabled Azure Service Bus namespaces anymore.

Comment: when I run the powershell command New-AzureSBNamespace 'SharePointAppServiceBus' -CreateACSNamespace $true -NamespaceType Messaging   it fails and error message points to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2017/06/01/upcoming-changes-to-acs-enabled-namespaces/?amp;clcid=0x409

Answer (score 2):

I am also facing the same issue here. Exact same error message. Unfortunately, I do not have an answer for the original problem but was able to carry out debugging of the RER (remote event receiver) using Remote Debugging in VS2013.

You can deploy the Provider Hosted App to your remote web in Azure and attach the Remote Debugger to the  deployed Remote Web. This will allow you to debug the Event Receiver.

For more info on Remote Debugging in VS2013/VS2012: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/05/remote-debugging-a-window-azure-web-site-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Hope this helps and hope we can find an answer to the original problem!

Comment: I think my problem is more PC related, when I do this in a fresh PC with vs 2013 installed it works, I suppose I have some components on my pc that make this thing fail.

Answer (score 0):

When event reciever is fired from sharepoint app, the endpoint is searched for.
If you are deploying your app on localhost then sharepoint online(I assume you are using to deploy sharepoint app) will fail to find your endpoint.

For remote event recievers to be called, either host it on azure or somewhere where the endpoint could be found by sharepoint online(globally available)

Comment: Are you sure that is correct?, the purpose of service bus is to be able to debug even with localhost. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/01/03/debugging-remote-event-receivers-with-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: Note comment: During F5 (debugging), if you are building a high trust app, you may not have any issues calling the remote event receiver service as long as your local SharePoint instance can reach the service. However, if SharePoint is not able to reach the service, the remote event receiver will fail to work in debugging mode.

Comment: The whole point of using the Service Bus Relay is to allow SharePoint Online to contact your AppEventReceiver when debugging on your 'localhost', so this answer is not valid. Obviously when deploying to Azure, SharePoint Online can contact your internet facing website so the service bus relay is not required